# samsung internet browser audio is not playing

Tags: android, html, audio, video, samsung-browser

I have created a dynamic video webpage, which consists of a < video > and < audio > elements, so I can change the sources of both elements dynamically. If I play the video, the audio is playing synchronously. So far, everything works. But if i using the Samsung Webbrowser on Android, it is not possible to play both < audio > and "< video > at the same time. If I start the video, the audio stops. If I start the audio, the video stops. Google Chrome does not make any problems, so assume it is a Samsung Internet Browser specific problem.

Comment: what happens it you mute the video?